# Continue script after do/until loop

Tags: loops, powershell

I'm trying to create a script where an executable is installed then a batch file will add a property to a properties file of the installed program.

To check for the batch file I wrote a `do`/`until` loop

```
do
{ Start-Sleep -S 2
}
until (Test-Path $batfile)
```

Now it should check if the process is available and then run the .bat property cmd

```
if ($(Get-Process -name $process -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -ne $null)
{
c:\file.bat set-property xyz true
}
```

Another idea is to check for the file until it gets unlocked and then run the property.

I'm having problems that the following commands won´t wait for the loop to finish. How do the following commands and loops need to be configured to wait first for the `do`/`until` loop is finished?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The code behind the do-until loop won't get executed before the `$BatFile` path is valid.

Comment: The process turns up later. How can I delay/loop the execution of the if cmd so that I can ensure the process is up as well and to set the property won't fail?

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow, this might be one of those [XY problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) please see the link and provide more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your question is:

> How can I delay/loop the execution of the if cmd so that I can ensure
>   the process is up as well and to set the property won't fail?

Just use a `while` loop where you just sleep two seconds until the process is up:

```
while((Get-Process -name $process -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null)
{
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
}
c:\file.bat set-property xyz true
```

Comment: That helps and works perfect. Thanks